# Bounded Convergent Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If I know from previously proved work that 
$$0 > \int_a^\infty p(s)f(- \int_t^\infty q(\sigma)d\sigma)ds > -\infty$$

where $p(s)>0, q(\sigma)>0.$

Wouldn't it be trivial that $$0 < \int_a^\infty p(s)f(\int_t^\infty q(\sigma)d\sigma)ds < \infty$$

This is just a very small part of a solution I am writing for a system of differential equations.

Clearly 
$$\int_a^\infty p(s)f(- \int_t^\infty q(\sigma)d\sigma)ds > -\infty \ \Leftrightarrow \ \int_a^\infty p(s)f(\int_t^\infty q(\sigma)d\sigma)ds < \infty$$

But, to be clear and concise for a reader, shouldn't I write a "proof" of the if and only if statement?
I believe I should, but again, it seems trivial.

Advice?

Comment: Is $f$ odd? Otherwise why would it be trivial? Or hold at all?

Comment: We only know $f$ is continuous and invertible. Through a similar derivation that allowed me to arrive to the first inequality, I can show the positive integral being less than infinity and greater than 0. But that is not feasible in the context of the paper. I see where I probably haven't given enough information and am expecting input with very little info. But, knowing that is there a clear way to indicate the if and only if statement?

Comment: But if one gets to it by a similar derivation why not just say it and leave the details - if interested - to the reader?

Comment: Yes they are non zero. I really want some clarifying statement. I know it sounds crude, but why can’t I just “divide both sides by -1” on the first integral inequality?

Comment: Also the function $f$ really doesn't depend on $s$? So it could be taken out of the integral?

Comment: But then you still have $-f(\cdot)$ which is not necessary $f(- \cdot)$.

Comment: No we can’t take $f$ out, it’s fixed.

Comment: The way you stated it now, the function $f$ is a function with respect to $t$ but the integral is one with respect to $s$. So the Integral doesn't care about what $f$ is doing so you can write it in front of the Integral. That is why maybe, you want to change that $t$ to a $s$ ?

Comment: @hal4math The only features of $f$ that are useful are:  $|f(uv)|\le M|f(u)| |f(v)| \ \ \forall u,v, \in \mathbb{R}$ and $rf(r) > 0$ for $r \neq 0.$ I think I can make an argument using the above since I already know the positive integral is less than infinity?